# Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater while using Spark 3.0.0 preview

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hadoop-streaming

I am getting this issue "Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater" while setting up kafka streaming along with spark 3.0.0 preview. How to resolve the issue.

Below are the Jars i used..

Spark 3.0.0 preview

spark-core_2.12-3.0.0-preview

spark-streaming_2.12-3.0.0-preview

spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview

kafka-clients-2.4.1

streaming-kafka_2.12-0.8.0

Comment: Based on searching Google and finding the GitHub page, I'd say try: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12